# Django request.user.is_authenticated provokes dictionary update sequence element #0 has length X; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

Every time my code reaches a certain line it seems to provoke a `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length X; 2 is required` error. 
The value X can change, but the error is almost always provoked when this is called:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated
```

It's `python 3.6.7`, `django 2.1.7`

Here is the error stack

```
    Traceback:

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "./playerdata/api/tokens.py" in token_queries
  87.     if request.user.is_authenticated:

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  213.             self._setup()

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  347.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in <lambda>
  24.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in get_user
  12.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_user
  189.             user = backend.get_user(user_id)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in get_user
  98.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  390.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1289.                 joinpromoter.add_votes(needed_inner)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_votes
  2171.         self.votes.update(votes)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py" in update
  620.                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

The code around request.user.is_authenticated:

```
def token_queries(request):    
    data = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        data = login_required(request)
    if data is None:
        data = anonymous(request)
    return json_response(data)
```

**EDIT: Additional info**

I must precise that this error is triggered once a day, towards my peak of activity on the website. Once it is trigger, it will keep spamming for a few hours before stopping.
It also doesn't happen only in the tokens,py file, but almost everywhere in the code where the user is trying to be accessed.

**UPDATE: Something to do with the Load Balancing**

The error seems to be linked to **load balancing**. When the error starts spamming, it will only happen on one of the LB node at a time.
I discovered that taking a node out of my load balancer will stop it from happening. **It doesn't even have to be the node on which the error happens**!
If I put both nodes back on, the error starts triggering again immediately.

For example:

- Node 1 starts spamming the error
- I take node 2 out of the LB
- Error stops
- Put node 2 back up, error spamming restarts instantly

The only way to stop it is to restart the machine hosting the node on which the error happens.

Adding 1hour stickiness to the LB didn't solve the issue.

I am running Django through Nginx, on a AWS server.

Comment: Show us the code of `def token_queries()` in *tokens.py* around line 87

Comment: @dirkgroten added the code. This error happens in almost all places where I try to get the user.

Comment: How's your user model defined? What's the value of `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings?

Comment: I am using the default AUTH_USER_MODEL (never changed the value)

Comment: What are you using for your sessions? Default django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware? And default SESSION_BACKEND?  Can you set a breakpoint before your `if request.user...` and print `request.session['_auth_user_id']`

Comment: Using `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` and no change was done one `SESSION_BACKEND`. Unfortunately, this bug only happens in production and I cannot reproduce it locally to use a breakpoint. It will also work fine for days on end, but then suddenly be triggered and spam the error for hours before finally stopping...

Comment: Looking at the Django code I think this error might be triggered if something’s wrong in your session. Possibly a corrupted entry in your sessions table. You might want to clear expired sessions (if you don’t have a cron job that does that already regularly) and then take a direct look at the db sessions table in production to see if you can spot a corrupted row.

Comment: Actually you should add a try except for now around your failing statement to print some extra info to the logs when the exception is raised. For example log the request session cookie so you can later retrieve that session in a shell in production.

Comment: What makes you think that it comes from corrupted sessions entries? Actually, I used to also have this error triggered by another one saying `'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'` so you might be onto something.

Comment: @dirkgroten tried some heavy solution and deleted all the sessions in django_session.... Unfortunately, the error is still spamming.

Comment: What made me think it’s something to do with the sessions is that I think the way to get your error is if `user_id` that gets extracted from the session isn’t an integer. I think adding some specific logging is the only way to get more information. Try to log as much information as possible when the error is raised.

Comment: It's not a problem linked to your User Model but I think in your urls.py. Show us the url file of the app

Comment: @Wariored What do you have in mind? If possible I'd like to only show more of the code only if really necessary. The app will work fine 90% of the time, but once every 2 days or so, the error I am talking about will start spamming non-stop for hours on end.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the url.py that points to token_queires function?

Comment: Which session middle ware  and authentication back-end  are you using ?

Comment: @sun_jara, there is really nothing special about the url file. What sort of issue are you looking for?

Comment: @DevangPadhiyar `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`, `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` and in settings: `SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"`. I am also using django rest framework.

Comment: Any custom middleware?

Comment: @Trent no custom middlewares :(

Comment: Judging by the line `user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)` in the error stack, I think something is wrong with your database query response. That also explain why it only happens on production. What kind of SQL database are you using?

Comment: This error happens quite deeply in the ORM; the `add_votes` logic determines whether or not a `LOUTER JOIN` should be used instead of an `INNER` one. Could you provide more details about which WSGI server your are using. Is it Apache's `mod_wsgi` by any chance? Also, do you have a custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL` that does anything funky with it's base manager?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with sessions, middleware, or database backend. The issue happens during `UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)` query construction while determining which kind of `JOIN` should be used.

Comment: @gdlmx I am using MySQL with INNODB

Comment: @RyanPergent absolutly same, lets help each other and post all software versions:

nginx 1.19.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
django "==3.0.9
python3.6
pipenv, docker

Gunicorn started with next line (this this might be important):

`gunicorn conf.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 5 --worker-connections=1000`

Comment: @IvanBorshchov Stack Overflow also requires that there be enough information in the question to be able to duplicate the problem. Our format isn't intended for just guessing as to why something is happening. Based on the problem description, this also appears strongly related to a production system configuration issue, not a programming issue, which makes it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. There may be a programming solution to the problem, but if so, a [MRE] that actually allows *duplicating the problem* needs to be provided in the question.

Comment: @Makyen the main question of this question is HOW TO create a steps to reproduce, it happens really often. Such problems are very rare because happen after month of production work. And it is absolutely hard reproduce them.

It is a pity that the question was closed. It could save many people and develop the industry as a whole. The inability to reproduce simply postpones the problem and makes the next framework unusable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check that the [SECRET_KEY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#secret-key) setting is the same on each of your nodes.

Just a hunch based on your load balancing and session comments.

Comment: Both nodes have exactly the same code (synced repository). If the Secret key was wrong, the error would happen all the time, not periodically, right?

Comment: Agree, look pretty odd, same issue for me, secret key is stable

Answer (score 1):

I can identify an abnormal line in your error trace:

> ```
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py" in update
>   620.                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
> ```

In normal condition this line should never be reached. 
If you look into the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fb352413c1fac65823f274feeb369cd5ab1af2e4/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L620) in "collections/__init__.py",

```py
if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):
    ...
        super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
```

The variable `iterable` was passed down from variable `needed_inner` 
in function [`_add_q`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dd0aa9dccab6c2dd7124061e25be37eeddadc3c2/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1289). Its type should always be `<class 'set'>`.  Therefore, `isinstance(iterable, Mapping)` should never be `True`.

As you said that you didn't use a custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Thus, the most plausible explanation is a hidden bug within the Nginx WSGI python implementation (maybe related to load balancing).